# Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure

Fast question is it possible to have [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/)

I would like to rent dedicated servers in 3rd party suppler and to load balancer from Azure

Question 1:
Can I setup this scenario? and use the load balancer from Azure?

Question 2:
Will I pay Outgoing bandwidth

Question 3:
Will you share for website with 10 000 000 page views per month how much  you pay for DNS look ups as average.

Question 4 please suggest same service competitors... Google, Amazon, Rackspace I already know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/) already answers #1 and #3.  Yes you can set this up.  Billing is done by DNS lookup at $0.75 per million lookup, so your 10m page views will cost at most $7.50, but this isn't taking into consideration DNS caching which will drastically lower this (already very low) cost.

Question 2 is not an Azure Traffic Manager related question.  No bandwidth goes through ATM so there is no charge.  I am sure you will pay bandwidth charges with whatever 3rd party datacenter provider you are going to use.

I don't understand question 4.  What do you want suggestions for?  A cloud provider?  There are lots of good ones but it depends on your scenario.

Comment: thank you. I have provider with unlimited bandwith / dedicated servers which I use them more than 10 year in fact 2 providers. Q4 was just to suggest some provider for example I like Rackspace but they say I need to pay $0.12GB  Amazon is not bad choice http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Answer (score 0):

Azure Traffic Manager is a DNS routing system. It is similar to the routing features of AWS Route 53 (although Route 53 is a more full-featured DNS system).

Azure Traffic Manager uses DNS to point incoming traffic to different endpoints, which can be either within Azure or external urls. Because it uses DNS, it doesn't actually see any of the data itself, it just translates something like `myapp.trafficmanager.net` to 'webserver1.example.com`or`webserver2.example.com` based on your rules and setup.

You can use round-robin, weighted or performance (which directs to the geographically closest address you have setup). You can further use Azure's DNS or another DNS system to use your own (sub)domain to CNAME to the trafficmanager.net domain name.

Load balancers like Azure Load Balancers and Amazon's Elastic Load Balancers are used to actually spread the traffic itself to different machines or services. Each work only with services hosted with the cloud provider so Azure Load Balancers can be used to load balance Azure VM's but not some servers you have hosted elsewhere.

Load balancers have bandwidth charges because they actually pass through the traffic. Azure Traffic Manager just has DNS query charges because that's all it does.

In your case, yes you can use Azure Traffic Manager to point to several external endpoints for your dedicated servers. You can also  nest Traffic Manager profiles so that you can first use geo-location then round-robin. Azure Traffic Manager does support basic http/https monitoring to make sure the endpoint is still active.

Because it is based on DNS, there will always be a lag between changes with the TTL value and how clients cache DNS addresses. This is inherent with all DNS routing. To be extra safe, you can use Azure Traffic Manager to route to your datacenter and then run your own load balancing software locally to spread the load among servers.